# How to display identical captions of nodes

Tags: graphviz

I wanted to draw RB-Tree as in Wiki [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Properties), [image: 1]

but I can't find a possibility of display of the identical caption for different nodes(in this case nil - nodes). It is possible?

```
  digraph "rb-tree"{
  bgcolor = whitesmoke;
  forcelabels = true;
  margin = 0;
  node [shape = circle,
        style = filled,
        fontsize = 14,
        margin = 0,
        fillcolor = black,
        fontcolor = white];
  edge [fontsize = 10,
        arrowhead = vee];
8 [fillcolor = red];
17 [fillcolor = red];
nil_8l [shape = box];
nil_8r [shape = box];
nil_17l [shape = box];
nil_17r [shape = box];
13->8;
13->17;
8->nil_8l;
8->nil_8r;
17->nil_17l;
17->nil_17r;
}
```

Comment: This question is very vague. Prepare yourself for downvotes. Not from me, but...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphiz has the possibility to set labels. So use:

```
 digraph "rb-tree"{
  bgcolor = whitesmoke;
  forcelabels = true;
  margin = 0;
  node [shape = circle,
        style = filled,
        fontsize = 14,
        margin = 0,
        fillcolor = black,
        fontcolor = white];
  edge [fontsize = 10,
        arrowhead = vee];
8 [fillcolor = red];
17 [fillcolor = red];
nil_8l [shape = box label="nil"];
nil_8r [shape = box label="nil"];
nil_17l [shape = box label="nil"];
nil_17r [shape = box label="nil"];
13->8;
13->17;
8->nil_8l;
8->nil_8r;
17->nil_17l;
17->nil_17r;
}
```